# Pattern only matches once per invocation and make is deleting intermediate files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following rules in a Makefile to build an executable in 3 stages:

```
all: build/myexe

build/myexe: output/main_dats.o output/foo_dats.o | build/
    gcc $^ -o $@
output/%.o: output/%.c
    patscc -c $< -o $@
output/%_dats.c: src/%.dats | output/
    patsopt -cc -o $@ -d $<
build/:
    mkdir -p build/
output/:
    mkdir -p output/
```

An `src/%.dats` source file is used to generate an `output/%_dats.c` source file which is compiled to an `output/%.o` object file and finally they are linked into the executable `build/myexe`.

Running `make` the first time will only successfully build the *first* of the two `.o` files:

```
$ make
mkdir -p output/
patsopt -cc -o output/main_dats.c -d src/main.dats
patscc -c output/main_dats.c -o output/main_dats.o
make: *** No rule to make target `output/foo_dats.o', needed by `build/myexe'.  Stop.
rm output/main_dats.c
```

But running again will build the second `.o` file and successfully link the executable:

```
$ make
patsopt -cc -o output/foo_dats.c -d src/foo.dats
patscc -c output/foo_dats.c -o output/foo_dats.o
mkdir -p build/
gcc output/main_dats.o output/foo_dats.o -o build/myexe
rm output/foo_dats.c
```

and note that at the end of each invocation the command `rm output/..._dats.c` is deleting the generated `.c` source file.

Here is a Makefile written without pattern matching:

```
all: build/myexe

build/myexe: output/main_dats.o output/foo_dats.o | build/
    gcc $^ -o $@
output/foo_dats.o: output/foo_dats.c
    patscc -c $< -o $@
output/main_dats.o: output/main_dats.c
    patscc -c $< -o $@
output/foo_dats.c: src/foo.dats | output/
    patsopt -cc -o $@ -d $<
output/main_dats.c: src/main.dats | output/
    patsopt -cc -o $@ -d $<
build/:
    mkdir -p build/
output/:
    mkdir -p output/
```

which works more predictably:

```
$ make
mkdir -p output/
patsopt -cc -o output/main_dats.c -d src/main.dats
patscc -c output/main_dats.c -o output/main_dats.o
patsopt -cc -o output/foo_dats.c -d src/foo.dats
patscc -c output/foo_dats.c -o output/foo_dats.o
mkdir -p build/
gcc output/main_dats.o output/foo_dats.o -o build/myexe
```

and note that the generated `.c` files are not being removed any more.

Apparently I am misusing the pattern matching mechanism. I know there is some kind of wildcard function but I believe it is intended for file globbing.

Comment: What's the output of `make -Rd` on the first execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid removing intermediate files, you just need to list them as actual targets somewhere.  For example you could write a separate rule:

```
make_srcs: output/main_dats.c output/foo_dats.c
```

You don't have to list this target `make_srcs` as a prerequisite, or provide it a recipe, etc.  Just listing the `_dats.c` files as actual targets or prerequisites in the makefile is enough to keep them from being deleted.

As for your "only building some output" behavior, I don't know: it works fine for me:

```
$ make --version | head -n1
GNU Make 4.2.1

$ cat Makefile 
all: build/myexe

build/myexe: output/main_dats.o output/foo_dats.o | build/
        touch $@
output/%.o: output/%.c
        touch $@
output/%_dats.c: src/%.dats | output/
        touch $@
build/:
        mkdir -p build/
output/:
        mkdir -p output/

make_srcs: output/main_dats.c output/foo_dats.c


$ rm -rf output build && make
mkdir -p output/
touch output/main_dats.c
touch output/main_dats.o
touch output/foo_dats.c
touch output/foo_dats.o
mkdir -p build/
touch build/myexe
```

So there's something about your setup which hasn't been made clear in your question.  As the comment suggested you need to run `make -d` (I would leave off the `-R` option, I don't know why you'd add that) and figure out why make throws that error.

Comment: As I'm sure you know adding `-R` trims down the debug info, as far as I can tell OP's issue won't have anything to do with remaking makefiles or the built-in rules.

Comment: I guess you mean `-r`; `-R` removes built-in variables not rules.

Comment: `-R` removes both.

Comment: Thank you the suggested rule listing the `.c` files as a prerequisite prevented them from being removed.

As for the pattern only matching once per invocation, I found the Make version was 3.81 (provided for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and upgrading to Make version 4.2 (found here http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/) has removed that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern rules should ideally be deprecated. They are prone to over-matching (because, well, patterns), they can be hard to get working, they bring with them the whole "intermediate target" issue (that's the deletion of `output/*.c` files that you are observing), they need *another* dubious feature ("secondary expansion") to make them usable in some more involved scenarios, etc.

In short: using pattern rules is not advised, and using multi-level pattern rules is *definitely* not advised.  Just more trouble than it's worth.  IMHO, anyway.

(end rant)

So I suggest that you write a simple macro instead, so your makefile ends up looking like this:

```
all: build/myexe

# $(call dats,basename)
define dats
output/$1_dats.o: output/$1_dats.c
    patscc -c $$< -o $$@
output/$1_dats.c: src/$1.c | output
    patcc -cc -o $$@ -d $$<
endif

build/myexe: output/main_dats.o output/foo_dats.o | build
    gcc $^ -o $@
$(eval $(call dats,foo))
$(eval $(call dats,main))

build:
    mkdir -p build
output:
    mkdir -p output
```

Comment: 100% disagree with your "rant".  Pattern rules are far simpler to use and understand than eval/call, and a lot easier to work with.  If your rules are complex enough to require secondary expansion then maybe eval/call is a good alternative, but secondary expansion is rarely needed (I almost never use it).  Certainly it's not needed in this example.  Removing intermediate targets is trivially avoided, simply by listing them as targets.  And pattern rules allow you to create multiple targets with a single recipe invocation, which is critical in many situations.

Comment: Fair enough! Those style preferences seem to be largely path-dependent (experience-and-taste-dependent, that is).  For instance, I definitely find the "treat Make as sort of Ninja on the bottom, eval/call for anything higher-level" approach much more usable (and debuggable, BTW -- just substitute `info` for `eval` and see the problem, certainly beats poring over `make -d` output) than patterns etc.  The "simply by listing them as targets" bit is quite telling -- I just can't keep such trivia mentally paged-in because I don't spend all day writing makefiles...

Comment: And perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but if you have to compile, say, 10,000 .c files, I can't imagine not using pattern rules.

Comment: @Mort why?  Either you know what those .c files are (in which case no problem -- just iterate `eval` over the list) or you use `wildcard` to find out, in which case see above.  Aside: to see how big boys use make these days, it might be enlightening to take a look at the AOSP build system -- it's gmake-based, with not even one pattern rule in sight (and the Android source tree is, needless to say, well, pretty big).  It's macros all the way down