# Error installing Frama-C with opam (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: frama-c, opam

Trying to install Frama-C with the recommended opam method gives the following error:

```
### stdout ###
# Cleaning     Installation directory
# Installing   WP shared files
### stderr ###
# /bin/sh: 1: src/plugins/wp/share/instwp: not found
# make: *** [src/plugins/wp/Makefile:355: install] Error 127
```

here are the commands used:

```
# install opam
$ wget https://raw.github.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/opam_installer.sh -O - | sh -s /usr/local/bin
# configure opam
$ eval `opam config env`
$ opam config setup -a
# install frama-c
$ opam install frama-c-base
```

Edit: here is the output of `opam install -v frama-c-base`: https://pastebin.com/eMH08ugA

Edit2: the system in question is running Linux Mint 17.3 (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS upstream); the Ubuntu package in the software repository is Make 3.81 (untested) although this had already been upgraded to Make 4.2 when this bug was encountered

Comment: More information is needed. Could you provide the output of `opam install -v frama-c-base`, so that we have the output of the commands launched during compilation? Note that the resulting output will be large, so that you may want to redirect it to a file, e.g. with `opam install -v frama-c-base | tee opam.log` and provide a link to `opam.log`.

Comment: opam.log: https://pastebin.com/eMH08ugA

Comment: This is not a direct solution to your installation problem, but would you be able to switch to OCaml 4.02.3? There is a newer release of Frama-C (20161101) available with that compiler, which should hopefully prevent that issue from happening. It has the added benefit of bringing general improvements and bug fixes over the previous version.

Comment: I would also recommend installing package `frama-c` directly, instead of `frama-c-base`. The only difference is that `frama-c` includes some extra dependencies, for instance if you want to be able to run the GUI. You should only opt for `frama-c-base` if you cannot install `frama-c` directly (e.g. your system does not have compatible C packages for some dependencies). You may use `opam install depext; opam depext frama-c` to help installing external dependencies (e.g. C libraries) used by Frama-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue, and the culprit seems to be Make 4.2, due to [this bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44742) in particular:

> bug #44742: Double-dep with double-colon rule not built [in parallel builds]

Several rules in Frama-C makefiles use double-colon, and by default the `-j%{jobs}%` is set in the `opam` Frama-C file to speed up the compilation.

Unfortunately, it seems that the combination of these two results in the `instwp` file (among others) not being built, despite its rule being present in the WP makefile, when using that specific version of Make.

I am using Make 4.2.1 by default and I do not have that issue (all files are produced as expected and `make install` succeeds). If I manually compile Frama-C without `-j`, I also do not have the issue.

If you are unable to update your version of Make, you could try using `opam install -j 1 frama-c`, which should override the `jobs` variable and disable parallel compilation of Frama-C, thus avoiding the error.

Still, my general recommendations would be:

1. Install a newer OCaml (4.02.3 at least, it should be compatible will almost every package available in OCaml 4.02.1) to ensure the most recent release of Frama-C will be available (Frama-C Silicon is not available in OCaml 4.02.1);
2. If you can, install `frama-c` itself, and not `frama-c-base`, since the only difference are the required packages, namely those for the GUI. You may want to do the following before running `opam install frama-c`:

   ```
   opam install depext
   opam depext frama-c
   ```

   The first line will install `depext`, which is able to find external dependencies for your distribution, and the second line will apply depext to Frama-C, thus prompting you to install external dependencies available in your distribution.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I'm not sure why I ended up with OCaml 4.02.1, prior to installing opam there was no ocaml compiler on my system.

Comment: 4.02.1 is the default version installed by `opam_installer.sh`. Maybe they should update it by now, but that could break existing scripts, I imagine...

Comment: By the way, if you could add the distribution you are using to the question, this could help guide users who often google using expressions such as 'frama-c opam error ubuntu' or something like that... and it would also help us know if there is a major distribution that would be impacted by this Make issue.

Comment: Done. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS repository provides Make 3.81 which I had already updated recently due to a bug in pattern substitution rules http://stackoverflow.com/a/42748870/2466305